# Can't get addListener function to work

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I have a combo box with a list of values that I want to use to trigger text in another input field.

I.e. If someone chooses a specific beach it displays the information on whether or not dogs are allowed off the leash in that zone.

I have written a couple of functions but it doesn't seem to want to trigger.

```
function initListeners(){       
    addEventListener(document.forms[0].cboBeachSelect, 'change', DisplayBeachZoneInfo);
}

function DisplayBeachZoneInfo () {
    alert("Yep this works");
}
```

I've just made a test alert box to pop up before I attempted to fill the text box (called txtBeachZoneInfo) but it's not firing anything.

It's been YEARS since I've done any JavaScript so I'm not sure if syntax has changed so any help would be appreciated.

*** EDIT ***
It's a standalone .js file that gets called from an eForm. There's no surrounding HTML. I have done it before using this method in this same context but it just won't work today!

*** EDIT2 ***
Just so I know for next time, what is it that I did incorrectly to earn downvotes on my question. Not being defensive, just would like to know so I can avoid it in the future and ask better questions.

Comment: can you post the relevant part of your HTML to support your question?

Comment: Off-topic: You should use `document.forms[0].elements.cboBeachSelect`, with `elements`. That's the proper way to get form elements, even if most browsers don't need it.

Comment: That's not how you use `addEventListener`.... and it's syntax hasn't been changed.

Comment: Thanks @Derek朕會功夫, but could you tell me HOW I should be using it?

Comment: You also aren't capitalizing it correctly. You should learn to use your browser's developer tools. You would have an error in you console.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara - can you please tell me what I'm not capitalising?

Comment: pay attention to your syntax lols..addEventListener.. uppercase the letter e

Comment: Changed. Hasn't made a difference to my problem though.

Comment: @CodeSlayer i believe camelCase is the right term for that.

Comment: @AlisonWonderland - Take a look at the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener). Since `addEventListener` is a method of `Element`, `document`, and `window`, technically your code is syntactically correct. However it is not doing what you were expecting because you are adding listeners to `window`, instead of your target element `document.forms[0].cboBeachSelect`.

Answer (score 2):

If you check your console, you will see the errors.

[`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) is a method of [`EventTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget) instances, not a global function.

You should use it like:

```
document.forms[0].elements.cboBeachSelect
    .addEventListener('change', DisplayBeachZoneInfo);
```

You may want to pass `false` as the third argument `useCapture` in order to make it work on some old browsers.

Comment: Ok, thanks for that, I appreciate the help. I've changed it and it's still not throwing up my alert box when I change the value in the combo box. 

Any other ideas that I could try?

Comment: You might have meant "objects implementing the [*Event Target interface*](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#interface-EventTarget)". :-)

Comment: @RobG Yes. Isn't it the same?

Comment: `addEventListener` *is* a global function in web browsers (`window` does have this method) ;)

Comment: @Oriol—just splitting hairs. Event target is an interface implemented by various objects (hence its name, [Interface EventTarget](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#interface-EventTarget)), it's not a "class" or constructor function so you can't create instances of it, however you can create instances of objects that implement it.

Comment: @RobG Ah, yes, it's an illegal constructor. I just meant `instanceof EventTarget` gives `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out adding the following to the .js file that's attached to my eForm works.

```
  if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener('load', initListeners, false);
  }
  else if (window.attachEvent) {
    window.attachEvent('onload', initListeners );
  }
```

Thanks to everyone who tried to help.